# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' preg_match

Tags: php

I keeping getting the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' on line 97
```

Line 97:

```
if (preg_match('/['.unichr(0x1F300).'-'.unichr(0x1F5FF).unichr(0xE000).'-'.unichr(0xF8FF).']/u'), $_POST['username'])) {
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You close a parenthesis before 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (preg_match('/['.unichr(0x1F300).'-'.unichr(0x1F5FF).unichr(0xE000).'-'.unichr(0xF8FF).']/u', $_POST['username'])) {
```

Remove the `)` right before the `,`

It might be easier to spot this way:

```
 $pattern = '/['.unichr(0x1F300).'-'.unichr(0x1F5FF).
            unichr(0xE000).'-'.unichr(0xF8FF).']/u';
 if (preg_match($pattern, $_POST['username'])) {
```

A good reason to keep your lines short, and use a good IDE.